# Scraping data from various online stores

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, web-scraping, screen-scraping

First off, should mention that I have permission from the stores to scrape this data so legality isn't an issue here!

I'm trying to scrape information from various online stores, and store them in a database once every hour.

Example site: http://www.uptherestore.com/department/accessories

I've tried a [PHP scrape](http://www.devblog.co/php-web-page-scraping-tutorial/) like this:

```
<?php
$file_string = file_get_contents('http://www.uptherestore.com/department/accessories');
preg_match('/<div class="view view-uc-products view-id-uc_products view-display-id-page_3 storeview view-dom-id-1">
(.*)<\/div>/i', $file_string, $title);
$title_out = $title[1];?>
<p><strong>Accessories:</strong> <?php echo $title_out; ?></p>
```

but it's giving me errors of the ilk:

```
 [14-Feb-2013 07:39:49 UTC] PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::loadHTML() [<a href='domdocument.loadhtml'>domdocument.loadhtml</a>]: htmlCheckEncoding: encoder error in Entity, line: 7 in scraping.php on line 5
```

Full error from log file is here: http://pastebin.com/W2Bhkc0s

Even if I **do** manage to scrape from that site, it will only return the first page of results (when I need all pages). My current solution to this would be:

- Use jQuery to check how many elements are in the pager at the bottom of the page
- Run a loop that scrapes each of these pages

But this is no ideal - as you can see, at the bottom of the page there are pages 1...9 but if you click "last" there are actually 11 pages of content. In short, what's the best method to scrape data from sites like this? As mentioned the store owners have all given me permission to use their content, but they're not particularly technically minded and cannot give me access to their servers/put any code in their servers' .htaccess to allow requests from my website.

Comment: So do you need to do this in web client or on server?

Comment: JS/jQuery will not help you unless A. You're running it from an extension that is not subject to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) or B. The other site has a CORS enabled that allows yours to send requests. You will probably be doing this in the back end.

Comment: Why are you using ajax / javascript? This only needs a scheduled job (cron?) and a php script.

Comment: Preferably server - to lighten load on the client-side and to keep everything up-to-date I'd like to schedule the scrape once an hour, load it in a log/database that my front end can access.

Comment: @jeroen This is an entirely new type of programming to me so I'm unfamiliar with cron, will do a bit of research. Will that help me get past the multiple-pages issue?

Comment: A cron job (in linux, in windows you need the windows scheduler) is just one line that tells the system to run a script every xx days / hours / minutes / etc. The real script is the php script that scrapes the sites. You should get that to work by just calling it from a browser or the command line and when it does work, you schedule it. As it does not work, you should post the php code and error messages when you call just the script (no javascript / ajax stuff).

Comment: @jeroen Thanks for the explanation, that's what I assumed. Updated question to include PHP code I tried. I also tried a variant that would just get the title div, but that also returned the same errors.

Comment: @jeroen Also added pastebin of full error log here http://pastebin.com/W2Bhkc0s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your error message does not seem to fit your php code: The php is trying to parse the html using a regex (wrong!) and the error message suggests that you are using an html parser (DOMDocument) to parse the html (the right way).

What you would need to do is the following:

1. Get the html from a product page (like you are doing now...);
2. Check if that page has already been parsed in your database (see the next point);
3. Use an html parser to get the info from that page that you need and store everything in a database - including the link to the product page or another identifying property of that page and some sort of time-stamp so that you know what you have done already;
4. Use an html parser to get all product links in the html;
5. Go to 1. for every product link that you have found.

You probably need to build in some logic to make sure your script does not enter in a never-ending loop or runs too long, but that is basically it; no browser / javascript / ajax is required until you actually want to see the results of the operations in your browser.

Comment: This is a good answer. One bit I'm still not sure about - the "accessories" page linked above has 11 pages of accessories. However, it won't always have 11 pages (obviously, as more stock comes and goes). So how can I grab all that data and build logic around it? Should I just get the php to try grabbing page 1, 2, 3...infinity and when it hits a blank page it assumes that everything's been loaded?

Comment: @Jascination No, you should use an html parser and get all links (to get all links on a page) or all links with a certain class (for product links, depends on the page you are scraping). Then you follow these links and start the process all over.

Answer (score 1):

Paging is simple, you just find the link that says 'next' and follow it until it's not there anymore. Unless you're comfortable with xpath want a good html parser library (phpquery, simple-html-dom). Be prepared to spend a good deal of time figuring out the right way to do it, and above all, don't listen to anyone who tells you to use regex.

Answer (score 0):

Use cURL and regex to filter through what you need. Google cURL the php.net site will give you all the information you need

Comment: Got this up and running, although how can I navigate across multiple pages to scrape (see example site - there are 11 pages, although I need a way to check and automate this.